# Cannot catch websocket traffic from android by fiddler4

Tags: android, websocket, fiddler

I cannot catch any WebSocket traffic from an Android app.  When I use a web browser I can see all web traffic (and WebSocket also). I configured Fiddler according to this documentation:

[Configure Fiddler for Android / Google Nexus 7](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ConfigureForAndroid)

But this way can only catch API traffic. How can I catch WebSocket traffic?